# What is the difference between checkInterval and modificationTestInterval?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

What is the difference between checkInterval and modificationTestInterval?

checkInterval checks if the JSP page needs to be recompiled. Likewise, modifyTestInterval checks to see if it changes periodically.

The only other thing is whether development is true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options work **only** in development mode (cf. [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jasper-howto.html)):

- `checkInterval` decides how often to run **background** compilations, i.e. how often to recompile all known `*.jsp` files. This happens whether you access the page or not and the results are in the logs, so you don't have to refresh your browser page. If you access a JSP page from your browser a compilation attempt will **always** be run,
- `modificationTestInterval` decides how many seconds must pass between two compilations of **the same** file. If you compulsively save the file to disk, this configuration prevents the compiler to compile the JSP page every `checkInterval`. It also protects you from a broken system clock.